# How the persistence.xml file is different from hibernate.conf.xml file, in which scenario we should which file

Tags: jpa

i was going through the hibernate examples, in some examples persistence.xml was used in some examples hibernate.cfg.xml was used. what is difference between these two files and how these files can affect our project behavior and in which scenario which file will be the best.

i don't have any issue with either of these files, i just want know that is there any internal behavior change in project when we use these files.

in persistence.xml we have

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="hibernate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.test.jpa.Student</class>
    <properties>
      .....property tags
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

in hibernate_cfg.xml file we have

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ......property tags
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

both of my project run fine when i use these files, i just want to know the difference b/w these files.

Answer (score 0):

persistence.xml is the configuratoin file from JPA standard and hibernate.conf.xml is the Hibernate specific file.

It's recommended to use JPA standard as far as possible to be independent from the underlying JPA implementation.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i appreciate it. hope i'll keep getting the positive answers in future.

Comment: I'm happy to help. If my answer was helpful please accept it as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: i would like continue the discussion here, as i have read over the internet that JPA is just blueprint and ORM framework e.g Hibernate is having the actual implementation. can we create and run project with JPA only by not using any ORM framework like Hibernate, iBatis, is it true ?

Comment: No The JPA implementations are: Hibernate, EclipseLink, OpenJPA, DataNucleus. IBatis (now MyBatis) is not a JPA implementation.

Comment: Btw. StackOverflow is not a discussion platform. We are supporting people with technical problems. You should start your investigation on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API